# In javascript, how to know when the user clicks the page, or close the page?

Tags: javascript

My HTML looks as below:

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<iframe>...<iframe>
<body>
```

I tried several methods, such as body.onbeforeunload, onclick, onclick, but neither works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> how to know when the user clicks the page.

To find if user has clicked on the page, you can use `document.addEventListener`

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(event){
  alert("clicked");
})
```

> or close the page?

There can be two scenarios. Either you close the tab or close the window. 
Closing window cannot be detected.But events like [unload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536973(v=vs.85).aspx) & [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) can be used to detect when page is unloaded.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  alert('Are you sure');
};
```

These events will also fire when navigate from one page to another